# One login Developer account does not send email after signup

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, onelogin

For one login website, the free account setup does not send any email. tried few times with different email addresses

https://www.onelogin.com/developer-signup

Can anyone help here as soon as possible?

Comment: It will be best to just delete this questions. You already figured it out and it's of no value to anyone!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. It was in junk. Able to register and login:).